# How not to superimpose the bars in bcr.bar_chart_race python

Tags: python, bar-chart

I have a racing bar plot with bcr.bar_chart_race in Python. The data that I use is the word frequency use by a specific media (Journal de Bangui) in Central Africa during one year. My problem is that from month to month there are words that simply are not used anymore. Thus their bars start descending and superimpose with the others.As a result there are some words and bars that are unreadable.

How can I make the bars dissapear if they are not used in the next month? Below my code.

Thank you very much! I am really in a hurry

```
   import bar_chart_race as bcr
   bcr.bar_chart_race(df_bangui,
        sort='desc',
        n_bars=20,
        steps_per_period=50, 
        period_length=100,
        fixed_order=False,
        #interpolate_period=True,                 
        label_bars=False,        
        figsize=(8, 4),
        dpi=144,
        shared_fontdict={'color' : '.1'},
        filename = "Word Frequency\Bangui_by month_2.gif", 
        filter_column_colors = True, 
        cmap = "dark2", #it allows me to change the pallette of colours
        title = "Journal de Bangui - Word Frequency by month")
```

This is a screenshot of my racing bar plot:
[Racing bar plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9TVHV.png)

Answer (score 0):

When a word disappears in a particular month, do you represent that as the number zero in your input data ? If so, try removing the zeros. That is, if your input came from a .csv file, the input should look like this:
,,,,,,
instead of this:
,0,0,0,0,0,0,0